# Voltage Output Regulation for LTC3310

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I am regulating the voltage using the LTC3310 switching regulator. I need to obtain 0.73 V on the output which I chose the right resistors for in theory. However simulation on LTspice is giving other values. Below is the circuit I created on LTspice and its simulation. Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

And this is the simulation:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! That is strange considering 0.5 V Vref. What happens if you reduce R2 to compensate?

Comment: By R2 you mean the 100K resistor in my circuit?

Comment: No, R2 in your embedded schematic.

Comment: By reducing R2 to 30.5K I could achieve a 730mV output. But I still don't understand why this happens

Comment: Try adding a more significant load, say 100Ω, between the output and ground. Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: For R1=46k and R2=100K, the same problem, I am getting a higher voltage than expected

Comment: @Roy Have you posted the wrong schematic?

Comment: No this is the right one, only modifying R2 in the schematic above can provide the right solution

Comment: What’s your load? It’s made for 10 A and imposes a 35 ns minimum on-time so it may require pulse skipping on very light load.

Comment: The way it is connected, it should be running in forced continuous mode. I am presuming a load of 9A

Comment: Apparently, a load of 1ohm will work with the resistors in the schematic, however the output voltage will contain ripples

Comment: You need low ESR.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your help everyone

Comment: Why haven't you used a proper resistor for RT?

Comment: Connecting both RT and MODE/SYNC to Vin places the regulator in forced continuous mode with a frequency of 2Mhz